# Semigroups with the property $S=S^1(S\setminus S^2)$

Tags: semigroups, finite-semigroups

We have encountered semigroups $S$ which have the property $S=S^1(S\setminus S^2)$ (see [Equality of two specific classes of subsets of a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4736465/equality-of-two-specific-classes-of-subsets-of-a-group)), or equivalently $S\subseteq S^1(S\setminus S^2)$.

Are there any characterizations (or classifications) of such semigroups?

**Note.** It is obvious that a necessary condition is $S^2\neq S$ (i.e., $S^2\subset S$), thus $S$ must not contain any left or right identity element. Also, the property is equivalent to
$S^2=S(S\setminus S^2)$, because $S^1(S\setminus S^2)=S(S\setminus S^2)\dot{\cup} (S\setminus S^2)$ and $S=S^2\dot{\cup} (S\setminus S^2)$, where $\dot{\cup}$ denotes the disjoint union.

Every monoid does not have the property, but the additive semigroups $\mathbb{Z}_+$ and $(M,+\infty)$ ($M>0$) enjoy it.

Comment: It is worth stating the definitions (from the linked question) that $S^1 = S \cup \{1\}$ and $S^2 = S \cdot S$, because these are both nonstandard and a bit confusingly inconsistent. Also, what is $(M,+\infty)$?

Comment: Well, they are somewhat standard, but they are also confusingly inconsistent.

Comment: It is equivalent to say that $S$ is generated by $S \setminus S^2$.

Comment: @Sean Eberhard. $(M,+\infty)$ is an interval that is a sub-semigroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ if $M\geq 0$.

Comment: @Sean Ebrehard. Can you please clarify why $S=\langle S\setminus S^2\rangle$ is considered equivalent?